# zsh: Print variable with surrounding text if defined?

Tags: shell, zsh

I want to print a variable with some text before and after it, but to print nothing if it is not defined.  For example, consider a function `frotz` that formats a two-part message: the second part should appear in parentheses, but the parentheses should not be there if the second part is empty:

```
% frotz foo bar
foo (bar)
% frotz foo
foo
```

What is the implementation of `frotz`?  Obviously I can do it using an `if`, but I'd like something more concise, presumably using parameter expansion.  However, I haven't been able to find a good way to do it.  For example, this works:

```
print "$1${2:+ (}$2${2:+)}"
```

…but requires me to repeat `${2` three times.  Is there a way to do this that only requires writing the name of the possibly-empty variable once?  (For bonus points, I'd like a solution that also works in `bash`(1), but I'm mostly interested in `zsh`(1).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite what you asked for, but using the POSIX `:+` operator can eliminate one reference to `$2`.

```
frotz () {
  print "$1${2:+ ($2)}"
}
```

(`zsh` *might* have a way to do this with just one reference to `$2`, but it's not clear to me yet what that would be.)

Comment: One down is an improvement, at least.  I could have sworn I tried that and it didn't work — trying it again the parentheses backslashes in `zsh`, but it's otherwise fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found a `zsh`-specific way to do it, though it requires setting the `EXTENDED_GLOB` option first:

```
frotz () {
    print "$1${2/(#b)(?*)/ (${match[1]})}"
}
```

It unconditionally prints `$2`, but since `?*` only matches a *non*-empty string, an empty string still prints nothing, which is what I want, but a non-empty string gets the space and parentheses.  (The `(#b)` activates backreferences, which is the only way I can find to use the matched string in the replacement — the `${match[1]}`.  See `zshexpn`(1), "Globbing Flags".)

However, that's complicated enough that I just said "to heck with it" and made a function out of it, and both caller and callee are more readable for it.